# Android: ListView Custom Adapter. Resource not found Error

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, adapter, listview-adapter

Error Log:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
                                                                                          at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:299)
                                                                                           at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4138)
                                                                                           at me.axiom.aapp.ironbannercompanion.ListViewAdapter.getView(ListViewAdapter.java:43)
                                                                                           at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2347)
                                                                                           at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1270)
                                                                                           at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1182)
                                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17565)
                                                                                           at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:727)
                                                                                           at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:463)
                                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17565)
                                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5537)
                                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
                                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17565)
                                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5537)
                                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:391)
                                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17565)
                                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5537)
                                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17565)
                                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5537)
                                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17565)
                                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5537)
                                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                                                                                           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2615)
                                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17565)
                                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2045)
                                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1196)
                                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1409)
                                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1084)
                                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5990)
                                                                                           at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
                                                                                           at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
                                                                                           at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
                                                                                           at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

ListViewAdapter Class:

```
String url="http://bungie.net";

private Context context;
private GuardianInfo[] guardianList;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public ListViewAdapter(Context context, int resource, GuardianInfo[] object) {
    super(context, resource, object);
    this.context = context;
    this.guardianList = object;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_characters_content, parent, false);

    GuardianInfo guardian = guardianList[position];

    TextView textView_Class = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listView_CLASS);
    textView_Class.setText(guardian.getCharacterBase().getClassType());

    ImageView imageView_IMG = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listView_IMG);
    ImageView imageView_BG = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listView_BG);

    Picasso.with(context).load(url + guardian.getEmblemPath()).into(imageView_IMG);
    Picasso.with(context).load(url + guardian.getBackgroundPath()).into(imageView_BG);

    return convertView;

}
```

Now the error seems to occur when I attempt to change the text of the textView_Class. It says the resource could not be found.

Also I am setting the ListAdapter via

```
GuardianInfo[] guardians = response.body().getResponse().getData().getCharacters();

ListViewAdapter adapter = new ListViewAdapter(getBaseContext(), R.layout.listview_characters_content, guardians);

ListView listView_Characters = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView_Characters);
listView_Characters.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: What does guardian.getCharacterBase().getClassType() returns? In case it returns an integer you must be careful because it is handled by setText as a resource id and not as a string to be displayed as is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Exception, it looks you are setting some int value to your TextView. When you are setting an int value to your TextView, it thinks that you are trying to set the text with a String resource with ID equal to your int value which in your case may be this `guardian.getCharacterBase().getClassType()`. Try replacing your this line

```
textView_Class.setText(guardian.getCharacterBase().getClassType());
```

with this

```
textView_Class.setText(String.valueOf(guardian.getCharacterBase().getClassType()));
```

Comment: Yes, it was returning an integer. What I will do is change the text depending on what the integer is.

Answer (score 0):

Show your List item layout... R.layout.listview_characters_content